# Taskbar dock panel with multiple rows

Tags: linux, gratis, open-source, window-manager

Annoyed with KDE 4.13, namely not being able to disable baloo, I'm again looking for alternatives. I'd prefer something lightweight, probably OpenBox, but what I miss most in all the alternatives I have tried out so far is a flexible taskbar panel. The ideal panel for me should

1. contain at least desktop switcher, window switcher and notification area,
2. show only windows from current desktop,
3. display more than one row of icons, both for the window list and the notification area,
4. have configurable size,
5. not try to automatically order windows,
6. allow rearranging windows using drag & drop,
7. never group windows of the same application,
8. look pleasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that with a bit of configuration, [`xfce-panel`](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/start) satisfies all my needs.

1. Adding elements works via context menu: “Panel / Add New Items…”. Adding a stretchable separator after the window buttons (i.e. taskbar) made sure that items following that stayed at the right side of the bar no matter how many tasks I have.
2. Configurable via context menu: “Properties… / Show windows from all workspaces or viewports”
3. Context menu “Panel / Panel Preferences…”, where I set the “number of rows” to 2.
4. The same dialog I just mentioned, a slider labeled “row size”.
5. Properties of the window buttons item (like 2.), ”Sorting order: None, allow drag-and-drop”.
6. See 5.
7. Same dialog, “Window grouping: Never”.
8. Some gtkrc editing, based on [these tips](https://wiki.xfce.org/tips#gtkrc_files), allowed me to change the background color of the bar consistently, including the notification symbols and everything.

Comment: `xfce-panel` was on my mind since I've seen title :)